# What is the fastest way of inserting data to Hbase?

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase

I try to insert data to Hbase in the shortest possible time. I try in the way shown at the bottom however I get an error shown below. Does anyone have an idea what is wrong and how can I solve this? Maybe `hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv` is more efficient? Or maybe I should use PySpark or maybe even another tool? What gives me the best performance? If any additional information is required just let me know. Thank you in advance.

**ERROR**

```
Connect to HBase. table name: rfic, batch size: 1000
Connected to file. name: /path/to/hbase/logs2.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insert-data2.py", line 87, in <module>
    batch.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/happybase/batch.py", line 60, in send
    self._table.connection.client.mutateRows(self._table.name, bms, {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 198, in _req
    return self._recv(_api)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 210, in _recv
    fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin()
  File "thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx", line 439, in cybin.TCyBinaryProtocol.read_message_begin (thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.c:6470)
cybin.ProtocolError: No protocol version header
```

Below is my source code but if you have any other working solution I will be grateful for sharing.

**insert-data2.py**

```
import csv
import happybase
import time

batch_size = 1000
host = "0.0.0.0"
file_path = "/path/to/hbase/logs2.csv"
namespace = "sample_data"
row_count = 0
start_time = time.time()
table_name = "rfic"


def connect_to_hbase():
    """ Connect to HBase server.

    This will use the host, namespace, table name, and batch size as defined in
    the global variables above.
    """
    conn = happybase.Connection(host = host,
        table_prefix = namespace,
        table_prefix_separator = ":")
    conn.open()
    table = conn.table(table_name)
    batch = table.batch(batch_size = batch_size)
    return conn, batch


def insert_row(batch, row):
    """ Insert a row into HBase.

    Write the row to the batch. When the batch size is reached, rows will be
    sent to the database.

    Rows have the following schema:
        [ id, keyword, subcategory, type, township, city, zip, council_district,
          opened, closed, status, origin, location ]
    """
    batch.put(row[0], { "data:log": row[1]})


def read_csv():
    csvfile = open(file_path, "r")
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    return csvreader, csvfile


# After everything has been defined, run the script.
conn, batch = connect_to_hbase()
print "Connect to HBase. table name: %s, batch size: %i" % (table_name, batch_size)
csvreader, csvfile = read_csv()
print "Connected to file. name: %s" % (file_path)

try:
    # Loop through the rows. The first row contains column headers, so skip that
    # row. Insert all remaining rows into the database.
    for row in csvreader:
        row_count += 1
        if row_count == 1:
            pass
        else:
            insert_row(batch, row)

    # If there are any leftover rows in the batch, send them now.
    batch.send()
finally:
    # No matter what happens, close the file handle.
    csvfile.close()
    conn.close()

duration = time.time() - start_time
print "Done. row count: %i, duration: %.3f s" % (row_count, duration)
```

Comment: Since you ask, have you tried PySpark's CSV reader? Any problems with it?

Comment: @cricket_007 I didn't try to use PySpark's CSV reader. I tried with MapReduce `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv ` and with script shown above but performance is very bad. Now I test `LoadIncrementalHFiles`. Can you show me how it could be done with `PySpark` to achieve the highest possible performance?

Comment: I haven't used Pyspark with Hbase. I was only asking if you had simply tried yourself since you're asking about it. I can say that Spark would almost always have better performance than MapReduce, but there's lots of settings to be tuned for both to get better results, though, I doubt MapReduce could be tuned well enough

Comment: @cricket_007 In accordance to your suggestion I try to use Kafka Data Ingestion into HBase via PySpark. However I have a problem with PySpark. Can you take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982485/why-rdd-is-always-empty-during-real-time-kafka-data-ingestion-into-hbase-via-pys)? I know that you don't have experience with HBase, but this problem is related to Kafka and PySpark. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest just printing each RDD on its own to the console first, or even using Stuctured Streaming, if possible. Plus, make sure you set your Kafka auto reset property to start at the earliest offsets. By default, it starts at the latest, so if you are not producting new data, you will see nothing

Answer (score 1):

It happens when Thrift Server is not running. You need to start Thrift on your HBase cluster with hbase-daemon.sh script:

```
 /<hbase_home>/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift
```

HBase Thrift interface allows other languages to access HBase over Thrift by connecting to a Thrift server. It works like a Gateway for HBase.

While connecting via happybase library, use the port where your thrift server is running.